# Private testnet transaction submitted but not executed

Tags: go-ethereum

I was able to setup a private testnet with geth and I was also able to deploy a contract which I previously tested in truffle and testrpc. I can also connect my meteor app to it. If I write some data to my contract with my app I see that the transaction was submitted but somehow it is not executed. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you have the tx hash you can check if it was processed from the geth console with eth.getTransactionReceipt("<tx_hash>")

Comment: Also you should check you have provided enough gas for the transaction, usually the default is to low.

Answer (score 1):

That is the result of:

```
eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xf6d91e281de023f09169ce4576a45428a0171b40b285a01660e6ae3a23151d33")`

{
  blockHash: "0x94d6a20f9a6cbb62f3c971d9d3a7d1cca60c2255e07945dc9936c8a71aa424a1",
  blockNumber: 2900,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 90000,
  from: "0x444a85e95e99996924cd725b4bdf9917d3acfe8b",
  gasUsed: 90000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0xdfa2f172f9b6426b83111d5d3f97b18377cc08c33da80d835ab5eaa4c51242d8",
  to: "0xff894cfbb157d9156763ae238db15d9cd51950a5",
  transactionHash: "0xf6d91e281de023f09169ce4576a45428a0171b40b285a01660e6ae3a23151d33",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

What can I find out from it?

Comment: The gas was too low. I set it to 120000. Now it is working